# ngOnDestroy is not triggered on route navigation until all pending subscriptions emit value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a multi page Angular 4 app.

The home page of the app is subscribing to multiple Observables to render a few things.

I am storing all the subscription handles and unsubscribing them in ngOnDestroy. Ideally when we navigate away from this page, the components on this page should get destroyed, ngOnDestroy should get called, and all the pending subscriptions should get cancelled.

The issue is when I navigate to a different page ngOnDestroy is not triggered until all the pending subscriptions have emitted a value.

The funny part is that it happens only the first time. If I come back to the home page and go to the previous page again, then the pending subscription that got started again, do get cancelled immediately.

Added consloe.logs in ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy of each page/component to confirm the flow.

Unfortunately, the code is too involved to add a plunkr for it. Just wanted to check with the community if anyone has seen this behavior and know the reason for it.

PS: I do have a workaround for this issue. I am subscribing to router events and using the NavigationStart to unsubscribe (shown below), but I do not want to add this to my every component.

```
`this.router.events.subscribe((event: any): void => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.dataSub && this.dataSub.unsubscribe();
    }
});`
```